# When I used function click on the chrome console I get undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, xpath

I am using a xpath trying to click but I get undefined.

```
$x('//*[@id="form-container"]/ul/li[8]/div/div[2]/a')[0].click();
```

You can click manually is there any other way that I can click on the console and I tried `$x('//*[@id="form-container"]/ul/li[8]/div/div[2]/a').click()` but does not work.

Comment: is the undefined means that there is not javascript on the method?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a click [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event) and [dispatch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) it on a html element

```js
var evt = new Event("click", {"bubbles":true});
document.addEventListener("click",e=>console.log("clicked",e));
document.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Comment: I created the event and run the command and here is what I get:
clicked MouseEvent {isTrusted: false, __satellite__: 35, screenX: 0, screenY: 0, clientX: 0, …}

Comment: If I manually click and I get the follow:
clicked MouseEvent {isTrusted: true, __satellite__: 29, screenX: 2189, screenY: 244, clientX: 909, …}

Comment: @RafaSotoChan What is it you are expecting?

Comment: $x('//*[@id="form-container"]/ul/li[8]/div/div[2]/a/span[2]')[0].click(); if I run the command that should display options like when you click buttons something else happen, both should have the same result

Comment: @RafaSotoChan Did you try `$x('//*[@id="form-container"]/ul/li[8]/div/div[2]/a/span[2]')[0].dispatchEvent(new Event("click", {"bubbles":true}));`

Comment: I just tried and I show me this result:
clicked Event {isTrusted: false, __satellite__: 17, type: "click", target: span.selectBox-arrow, currentTarget: document, …}
true

Comment: @RafaSotoChan What code are you using? What output are you getting when clicking? What output are you getting when you use the code in the console?